# Jquery find collection of objects and convert it to html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use jquery find() to get elements, it will return a collection of objects.

So, basically I run:

```
 $("#eventlist").find("span")
```

Now if I run:

```
 $("#eventlist").find("span").html()
```

It returns the html of just the first element in the object.

When I try

```
 JSON.stringify($("#eventlist").find("span"))
```

I get an error: DOMException: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement':

My question is, how could I get all elements in one big html string?

Comment: you want html of all in one place?

Comment: yes, just a big html string containing all "<span>content</span><span>content2</span><span>content3</span>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like

```
var array = $("#eventlist").find("span").map(function () {
    return this.outerHTML
}).get();
var html = array.join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alterate over each and can stroe html in some varaible, see the ouptut and see console

```js
var html="";
$("#eventlist").find("span").each(function(){

html+=$(this).parent().html();
})

console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="eventlist">
<span>content1</span>
<span>content1</span>
<span>content1</span>
<span>content1</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML)** in javascript

```
$("#eventlist").find("span").each(function () {
   console.log( this.outerHTML);
})
```